# Why can't you have compressed oxygen and nitrogen in the same tank?

Tags: everyday-chemistry

I just watched a movie about the Apollo missions. They wanted an oxygen/nitrogen atmosphere on the spacecraft. But they said it would be too heavy and expensive to use an oxygen tank and a nitrogen tank and also equipment to monitor and control the mix ratio, so they went with pure oxygen. Why couldn't they put oxygen and nitrogen together in one tank at the right ratio so then they would only need one valve to maintain pressure?

Thanks Karl. It's so obvious now that you mention it! Guess I'm too new here and it won't let me reply to your comment.

Comment: Because oxygen is consumed, and if you replace consumed oxygen with a mixture of oxygen and nitrogen, maintaining the atmospheric pressure, you end up with too little oxygen after a (rather short) while. A human consumes about 1 cubic meter of oxygen per day, and the volume of the these spacecraft was in the range of 12 cubic meters if I remember correctly.

Comment: Sorry, six cubic metres. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_Lunar_Module

Comment: Do you mean compressed air? That exists.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's based on false premise.

Comment: Ever fill your tires at a gas station? What are the twp main component gases in tge tank through which the air passes on the way to your tires?